# Change back to local undo from global undo in VSCode JupyterNotebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook

I used to rely heavily on the 'local' undo, i.e. Cmd+Z works specifically within a given JupyterNotebook cell.
Unfortunately, a recent update to VSCode appears to have changed it to a 'global' undo, i.e. Cmd+Z undoes changes across the whole notebook.
As one jumps around in editing notebooks this isn't very helpful.

I just wanted to ask if anyone else has encountered the same issue, and if it's possible to fix/change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an option in VSCode's settings called `Notebook: Undo Redo Per Cell`.  Does that work for you?

Comment: You can find the fix in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211578/jupyter-lab-ctrl-z-shortcut-only-for-selected-cell-rather-than-all-modified-o/70825213#70825213