# Jupyter lab: ctrl + z shortcut only for selected cell rather than all modified ones

Tags: shortcut, jupyter-lab

Here we go...

Recently with the new update of Jupyter Lab when I press the "ctrl+z" command the recovery process applies for all cells I modified before and I want only the cell I selected to be modified. How could I fix that?

Comment: Please see the discussion in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175352/why-does-my-jupyter-lab-cell-turn-orange-with-every-new-edit-or-when-i-type-in-i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo/redo changes inside the selected cell in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763795/how-to-undo-redo-changes-inside-the-selected-cell-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 5):

Recently I've also experienced the same frustrating problem. I'm adding a picture to illustrate how to disable document-wide undo/redo here.

JupyterLab -> Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor -> Notebook -> Ctrl-F to find "undo" -> check the box "Experimental settings to...".

After that remember to close and re-open JupyterLab

[image]

Comment: you saved me from going back to Jupyter notebooks

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a document wide history function introduced in JupyterLab 3.2.

You have either to:
1- disable document wide undo redo (in in `Advanced Settings Editor` → `Notebook`,)

```
 "experimentalDisableDocumentWideUndoRedo": true,
```

and reload the page.
Or
2- install a 3.1 jupyterlab with `pip install "jupyterlab<=3.1"` or if conda `conda install -c conda-forge "jupyterlab<=3.1"`

See:
@krassowski answer:
[How to undo/redo changes inside the selected cell in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763795/how-to-undo-redo-changes-inside-the-selected-cell-in-jupyter-notebook/68763972#68763972)

Related Github issue:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10791

Related Changelog:
https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/changelog.html#id116